# Sign in a user with Devise outside of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm trying to figure out a way to sign a user in using Devise. I know this is possible from a controller using the following helper:

```
sign_in(:user, user)
```

Unfortunatly, this helper does not works when called from a service or an initializer (I have an initializer from where I can identify a user but I want to be able to sign in) for example. Is there any way to do it outside of a controller? Maybe using Warden?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeService
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers

  def process(user)
    sign_in(user)
  end
end
```